# Submit works when form is invalid in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

The submit button doesn't submit the form which is the intended functionality when all fields are missing except Country. When I choose a country but leave the other fields empty, the form submits. Weird bug.

component.html:

```
<div class="city-edit">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <p *ngIf="this.id && !city"><em>Loading...</em></p>
  <form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <!-- Name -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Name:</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="name" required
             placeholder="Type a name">
      <mat-error *ngIf="this.form.controls['name'].errors?.['required']">
        Name is required.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <!-- Lat -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Latitude:</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="lat" required
             placeholder="Insert latitude">
      <mat-error *ngIf="this.form.controls['lat'].errors?.['required']">
        Latitude is required.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <!-- Lon -->
    <mat-form-field>
      <mat-label>Longitude:</mat-label>
      <input matInput formControlName="lon" required
             placeholder="Insert longitude">
      <mat-error *ngIf="this.form.controls['lon'].errors?.['required']">
        Longitude is required.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <!-- Country -->
    <mat-form-field *ngIf="countries">
      <mat-label>Select a Country...</mat-label>
      <mat-select id="countryId" formControlName="countryId">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let country of countries"
                    [value]="country.id">
          {{country.name}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
      <mat-error *ngIf="this.form.controls['countryId'].errors?.['required']">
        Please select a Country.
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
    <div>
      <button mat-flat-button color="primary"
              type="submit">
        {{ this.id ? "Save" : "Create" }}
      </button>
      <button mat-flat-button color="secondary"
              [routerLink]="['/cities']">
        Cancel
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

component.ts:

```
//other code
this.form = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  lat: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  lon: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
  countryId: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
});

onSubmit() {
  var city = (this.id) ? this.city : <City>{};
  if (city) {
    city.name = this.form.controls['name'].value;
    city.lat = +this.form.controls['lat'].value;
    city.lon = +this.form.controls['lon'].value;
    city.countryId = +this.form.controls['countryId'].value;
    if (this.id) {
      // EDIT mode
      var url = environment.baseUrl + 'api/Cities/' + city.id;
      this.http
        .put<City>(url, city)
        .subscribe(result => {
          console.log("City " + city!.id + " has been updated.");
          // go back to cities view
          this.router.navigate(['/cities']);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
    else {
      // ADD NEW mode
      var url = environment.baseUrl + 'api/Cities';
      this.http
        .post<City>(url, city)
        .subscribe(result => {
          console.log("City " + result.id + " has been created.");
          // go back to cities view
          this.router.navigate(['/cities']);
        }, error => console.error(error));
    }
  }
}
//other code
```

screenshots:
This works and doesn't submit:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHoQu.png)

This is where the bug happens and the form submits:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QN5ph.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntiG2.png)

Comment: The most important piece of code is missing. What does the `onSubmit()` method do?

Comment: @JSONDerulo edited it. i don't think it has something to do with the validation tho.

Comment: At every click of the Create/Save, you are going inside the onSubmit and executing the logic

Comment: I think in your `onSubmit()` method you need to check whether the form is valid

Answer (score 1):

By default, Angular doesn't prevent the `ngSubmit` event from firing when the form is invalid. It's up to you to handle the validation and form submission logic.

Consequently, you could try to put `this.form.valid` in your button and also in your function.

```js
onSubmit() {
 if (this.form.valid) {
   [...]
 }
}
```

While on your button you could try something like this

```html
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" 
        type="submit" disabled="!this.form.valid">
        {{ this.id ? "Save" : "Create" }}
</button>
```

Comment: But why doesn't it submit when the country field is missing? Surely something has this implemented under the hood. Maybe it's the angular material form module? But I didn't find anything about that in their docs.

Comment: It's doesn't submit because you peform this check 
`var city = (this.id) ? this.city : <City>{};
  if (city) {}`

Comment: No, this check checks if im in editing mode or in add mode, but you are correct, the form submits anyways and I just realized that the server responds with 500 error. the form is submitted with empty values. The author of this tutorial seemed like he forgot to handle the case if the form is invalid in the OnSubmit method like you did. Thank you.